# Separate the element after every 2nd ',' and push into next row in bash

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed, command-line

An example of my file looks like this:

```
201012,720,201011,119,201710,16
```

Output I want:

```
201012,720
201011,119
201710,16
```

Comment: Please specify whether or not the lines of the file always have an *even* number of fields.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using a Sed loop:

```
sed -e 's/,/\n/2' -e 'P;D' file
```

Ex.

```
$ echo '201012,720,201011,119,201710,16' | sed -e 's/,/\n/2' -e 'P;D'
201012,720
201011,119
201710,16
```

This replaces the second `,` with `\n`, then prints and deletes up the `\n`, repeatedly until the substitution is no longer successful.

BSD doesn't understand newline as `\n` in right side of `s` commands, this is a workaround for ksh,bash,zsh shells:

```
sed -e :a -e $'s/,/\\\n/2' -e 'P;D' file
```

Or, a general solution for (old) seds:

```
sed '
:a
s/,/\
/2
P;D
' file
```

Comment: Able to process mutiline files even if fields on a line are odd (not-even): +1

Comment: Doesn't work with BSD sed

Comment: @Isaac: It just prints it all on one line like: `201012,720n201011,119,201710,16`

Comment: @Jesse_b Ah, when is bsd going to accept `\n` as a new line? sigh ...

Comment: `: unescaped newline inside substitute pattern`

Comment: @Jesse_b Since it is bash based: Please try this: `sed -e :a -e $'s/,/\\\n/2' -e 'P;D;ta' file`

Comment: @steeldriver the `ta` is never executed since the pattern space never survives the `D`.  We can add an extra command after the `ta` to verify. So, this will suffice : `sed -e 's/,/\n/2' -e 'P;D' `

Comment: @Jesse_b use this on bsd: `sed -e 'y/,/\n/' -e 's/\n/,/' -e 'P;D'` to workaround the newline limitation.

Comment: @RakeshSharma thanks - I always forget that `D` starts a new cycle

Answer (score 5):

```
$ paste -d, - - < <( tr ',' '\n' <file )
201012,720
201011,119
201710,16
```

or, without the process substitution,

```
$ tr ',' '\n' <file | paste -d, - -
201012,720
201011,119
201710,16
```

This replaces all commas in the file with newlines using `tr`, then uses `paste` to create two columns separated by a comma from that.

If `tr` feels a bit too simple, you may replace it with `sed 'y/,/\n/'`, which does the same thing.

Comment: Not a multi-line solution. If the file contains a line with non-even number of elements, it will be joined with next line.

Comment: @Isaac That, I presume, would indicate an issue with the _data_.

Comment: Which a robust solution should expose clearly in the output. Me thinks.

Comment: Nice. Alternately pipe tr into `paste  -sd ',\n'`

Answer (score 4):

I was able to accomplish this with the following awk command:

```
awk -F, -v OFS=, '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i=i+2) {j=i+1; print $i,$j}}' input
```

This will loop through each column in the input (incrementing by 2 each iteration) and print that column plus the next adjacent column on a line before moving to the next.

```
$ cat input
201012,720,201011,119,201710,16
$ awk -F, -v OFS=, '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i=i+2) {j=i+1; print $i,$j}}' input
201012,720
201011,119
201710,16
```

Comment: If the number of fields (comma separated) is not-even: a line with a trailing comma will be printed (which should be "the best we can do").

Comment: @Isaac: A line with a trailing comma _should be_ what you want to indicate there is an empty column in a csv file.

Comment: Maybe, If you think of a missing field as equal to an empty field. But I think that `1,2,3,""` is not the same as `1,2,3`. ... And, the sed solution do not generate that trailing comma.

Comment: In a csv an empty field is a missing field.  You are right though.  `1` is not the same as `1,""`.  One is a csv and the other is not.

Comment: This is especially important when an earlier column is empty.  For example `,,value1,value2` would be necessary to ensure the values end up in the proper column

Comment: If a "proper csv" is required then your answer is probably correct. I can not find a mention to "csv", nor to "proper csv" in the question though. I may be confused.

Comment: OP is dealing with comma separated values (CSV), and is trying to create a file with two columns

Answer (score 1):

Using `xargs` and `printf`:

```
xargs -d, printf '%s,%s\n' < file
```

Output:

```
201012,720
201011,119
201710,16
```

---

The above code assumes each line has an even number of fields.  If not, `xargs` will print lone numbers and dangling commas.  But this somewhat slower code should plow through most anything:

```
tr , '\n' < file | xargs -n2 printf '%s,%s\n' | sed '$s/,$//'
```

Which can be sped up by increasing `-n2` to some reasonable maximum *even* number, *e.g.* suppose no number in the input is longer than 15 digits:

```
m=$(getconf ARG_MAX) m=$(( (m/16) + (m%2) ))
tr , '\n' < file | xargs -n"${m}" printf '%s,%s\n' | sed '$s/,$//'
```

Answer (score 1):

Another `sed` solution:

```
sed 's/\([^,]*,[^,]*\),/\1\n/g' file
```

This replaces each second comma with a newline.

Answer (score 0):

```
awk -F'\n' -vRS=, '{l=$1; $0=""; getline; print l RS $1}'
```

or

```
awk -F'\n' -vRS=, '{print $1 RS (getline > 0 ? $1 : "")}'
```

You can omit the `-F'\n'` if the fields don't contain spaces. Or set it to the same value as the record separator (eg. with `-F,`) if your fields may also contain newlines (if eg. in the output of `echo 1,2,3,4` the last field should be `4\n`, not `4`).

Comment: Only prints even field count. Why are not-even fields changed?

Comment: Try `echo $'201012,720,201011,119,201710,16,201705\n201709,115,201708,23\n201707' | awk -F'\n' -vRS=, '{l=$1; $0=""; getline; print l","$1}'`.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `grep` - beware not all versions support `-o` and that this will not work for an odd number of fields

```
grep -E -o '[^,]+,[^,]+' file
```

Or some overkill

```
gawk 'BEGIN{FPAT="[^,]+,[^,]+";OFS="\n"}; {$1=$1; print}' file
```